# class parameter missing final quote

Tags: java, string, parameter-passing, quotes, processbuilder

I have the following code

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass (String myString){
   myFlag=myString
   }
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Path to my application",  "variousflags", myFlag)
   Process p = pb.start();
   }
```

When I run

```
myClass("worddocument.doc")
```

pb doesn’t start. In debugging MyClass, I noticed that:

```
 myFlag ="worddocument.doc
```

without the final quote. For a flag to work in the ProcessBuilder, it has to within quotes.
I have to include the line

```
myFlag= myFlag.concat(""");
```

which gives me the error message in Netbeans "unclosed string literal". How can  get rid of the neatbeans error, or even better, how can I get the final quote back?
Thanks

Comment: @MikaelF You're right it be fixed with "\"" instead of """. BUT I thought somebody could tell me how to not loose the final " in the first place. I don't understand why it dissapears. I have other string flags in the process builder which keep their final quotes.

Comment: Are `stringFlag`and `myFlag` the same values? If so, are there other operations that might alter your `String`? As `String` is immutable, you could check that your `ProcessBuilder` is still using the same `String` instance that it was passed by using the `==` operator on the two conflicting strings. That way, you would see if it has been modified (which it obviously has been) by the time your debug check runs.

Comment: @MikaelF Apologies, stringFlag = myFlag, that's another editing error. Now there is just a single variable: myFlag.  Corrected now.

Comment: @MikaelF myFlag was not modified in anyway in my code, prior to having to add the final quote and getting rid of empty spaces. I just double checked.

Comment: The final quote is back! I commented out a few lines to do a test and realised that the process started without added the final quote. It must have been a java or netbeans bug...

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you can recreate it in another IDE (perhaps even [ideone](http://ideone.com/). In case someone else experiences this issue in the future, you should post your solution as an answer and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has disappeared now :-) It must have been a bug in netbeans or java...
Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the issue, and I am not sure exactly when it fixed itself. 
If encountering the same problem, I would suggest:
1-restarting computer, 
2-restarting Netbeans, 
3-commenting out

```
myFlag= myFlag.concat("\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stringFlag= stringFlag.concat(""");
```

will cause a problem since your ide thinks you close the String at the second quotation mark.

Try to escape the second quotation mark.

```
stringFlag= stringFlag.concat("\"");
```

Comment: Adding comma , in processbuilder constructior should solve this problem.
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Path to my application", "variousflags" ,myFlag);

Comment: @Stefan Lindner Thanks, that's what I needed. I tried it previously and it wouldn't work, I must have used / instead of \.

Comment: @ MayurB Sorry I already had , in my pb definition, I forgot to put them in my code. Will update now.